# How to run `chmod` command on boot on Android 10?

Tags: root-access, twrp

I have an Android 10 device whose bootloader is unlocked. I have downloaded its firmware, modified it and get the adb shell rooted in recovery. Following are the steps for it:

1. Download [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775)
2. Extract recovery.img and modified ramdisk/default.prop as follows:

```
 ro.secure=0
 ro.adb.secure=0
 security.perf_harden=0
 ro.debuggable=1
 persist.sys.usb.config=adb,mtp
```

3. Replace split_img/recovery.img-zImage with permissive kernel(built from kernel sources)
4. Repack it and flash it on the device.
5. Reboot to recovery and run adb shell. It will be rooted.

I want to add simple `chmod 666 /dev/diag` command and I have mounted system with stock recovery mount system option and then tried to do following:

1. Write chmod command at the end of init.rc.
2. Tried creating new rc scripts under /system/etc/init/ folder. New rc script has just chmod command written in it.
3. Tried appending(e.g. echo "chmod 666 /dev/diag" >> /system/etc/init/cameraserver.rc) chmod command in other rc files in /system/etc/init/ folder.

All were not able to change the required permissions. `init.rc` changes lost after reboot. Other files/changes persist after reboot but doesn't change the permission of diag port.

OTOH, I was able to make a system app with changes in /system/app/ folder.

Is there anything else that I can try to run the chmod command after phone boots?

Comment: `echo "chmod 666 /dev/diag" >> /system/etc/init/cameraserver.rc` won't work. You need to provide an `init` trigger (`on ...`) as well. Simple is to edit the `ueventd.rc` file (it must be from vendor, not AOSP) which creates `/dev/diag` device node. Replace the relevant statement inside that file to set whatever permission mode you want.

Comment: If that's an option for you: [tag:tasker] can react on the BOOT_COMPLETED event and run e.g. a terminal command as root, like `! chmod 666 /dev/diag` (the exclamation mark tells it to run the command as root).

Comment: @IrfanLatif `on property:sys.boot_completed=1` event helps me to change the /dev/diag permissions but it doesn't help me to change /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog permissions.. Any suggestion? I looked into ueventd.rc and there is no diag related changes..

Comment: @Izzy I think tasker can run it as su only if device is rooted but here I don't have a rooted device when it boots to system but only have rooted adb shell when it boots to recovery.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true. But your question uses the [tag:root-access] tag – which says "for questions spefically requiring root permissions". So that tag basically implies your device is rooted. Maybe you [edit] your question and clarify? While at tags: what part is about rom-flashing, and which about selinux or systemless-root? Just asking ;)

Comment: @IrfanLatif I have rooted system with modifying the prop.default file from recovery rooted adb shell and then modified the ueventd.rc of vendor as you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: @Izzy `root-access` as my device is rooted in recovery, `rom-flashing` flashed modified `recovery.img` and full firmware before that, `selinux` disabled it actually making permissive, `systemless-root` you can give ideas if I can install Magisk via rooted recovery :p

Comment: Your question is not about the flashing itself, nor about issues with selinux – so I'd remove those two definitely. As you basically ask for "any way to run that chmod", it's not about systemless root / twrp; if that's something you want to figure out, I'd make that a separate question (short answer: probably no, unless you patched out signature check from that recovery – or there's TWRP for your device). Those tags are irritating/misleading (note this is an *advice/recommendation,* not a "you have to").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "chmod 666 /dev/diag" >> /system/etc/init/cameraserver.rc` won't work. You need to provide an [`init` trigger](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#triggers) as well. For instance:

```
~# echo "on boot" >/etc/init/dev_diag_chmod.rc
~# echo "    chmod 666 /dev/diag" >>/etc/init/dev_diag_chmod.rc
~# chown 0.0 /etc/init/dev_diag_chmod.rc
~# chmod 0644 /etc/init/dev_diag_chmod.rc
~# chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /etc/init/dev_diag_chmod.rc
```

But even simple approach is to edit the `ueventd.rc` file (which is read and executed by Android's device manager) provided by vendor (since `/dev/diag` is a hardware specific interface) which creates the device node. Replace the relevant statement inside that file to set whatever permission mode, owner and group you want. E.g. you can replace:

```
/dev/diag    0660    system    system
```

With:

```
/dev/diag    0666    system    system
```