# What feature of Android provide security to reset the /system changes on reboot?

Tags: twrp, system, kernel, systemless-root, init.d

I am stuck in a weird situation where I have two Android 10 phones from Samsung. I have rooted the stock recovery of both device as instructions given [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223487/how-to-run-chmod-command-on-boot-on-android-10). The problem is when I change something via recovery like create a new /system/etc/init/custom.rc file then on One device it persist on /system after reboot but on another it doesn't. The changes does persist when I reboot to recovery back.

I want to understand which layer of Android applied this feature:

- Kernel
- Stock recovery
- System
- or another

Any suggestion? and how to fix it?

Comment: probably misleading but one thing i heard about recently is [FEC](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81989031&postcount=407)

Comment: I checked it in the kernel sources of both and its turned on(CONFIG_DM_VERITY_FEC=y) in both. Don't know what I am doing wrong. But its worth to know about FEC :) I should disable it as it will not affect the device functionality Right?

Comment: it is part of dm-verity and can be safely disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `avb` checks form `boot.img/ramdisk/fstab.qcom` has fixed the issue.